# Best way to port PyScripter+GTK programs from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a bunch of small python graphics programs that I developed with PyScripter and GTK on Windows. I was hoping to switch to Ubuntu, but PyScripter is not available in Linux, and Spyder does not take GTK.

Any suggestion on how to easily compile/run GTK on Ubuntu, with a GUI like PyScripter or Spyder? "Easily" is key, since I am not a Ubuntu Master.

Comment: Have you looked at GTK+ User Interface Builder (*glade*) from the Ubuntu Software Center? Glade is a tool to enable quick and easy development of user interfaces for the GTK+ toolkit.

Comment: karel, I just installed Glade, but I think it is different from what I need. Glade allows you to build window layouts with buttons, frames, etc. But what I need is a Programming workspace such as PyScripter or Spyder from where I can invoke GTK functions such as Create Drawing Area, Draw Rectangle etc.

Comment: PyScripter looks just like an IDE to me. There are lots of Python IDEs out there: look at PyCharm, PyDev, Eric, ... even most of general purpose IDES can do python.

Comment: Javier, PyCharm worked! As you answered in a comment, I can't give you credit. If you post your answer again ans an "answer" to the question, I will gladly close it.